# Using Sub-domain Routing

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need to create a subdomain routing for my app. The way I want it to work is, present a select menu for my users to select a school from then based on the school selected create a specific subdomain for the school. Something like: "school.mysite.com". Am confuse because the users only have to select school to a select form.

View

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'school', 'method' => 'GET', 'class' => 'form']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
        <select name="school" class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected disabled style="display:none">Select Your School</option>
        @foreach ($schools as $school)
            <option value="{{ $school->short_name }}">{{ $school->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Enter School</button>
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Routes

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{school}.mylungu.dev'], function () {
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'school', 'uses' =>     'HomepageController@enterSchool']);      
});
```

Controller

```
public function enterSchool(EnterSchoolRequest $request)
{
    $sch = $request->input('school');
    $school = School::whereShortName($sch)->first();
    $ads = Ad::whereSchool($school->id)->get();
    $categories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')->with('children')->get();

    return \Redirect::route('school', [$sch]);
}
```

Comment: have you set the DNS to accept wilcard subdomains ?

Comment: Actually am currently working locally with homestead